# I can't change className using hooks please suggest me what to do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

I cant change my class name using hooks please look into it.
I am learning react from code with harry and also tries exactly he did....

Comment: use back ticks not  single quotation `'`

Comment: You have to use backticks instead of single quotes

Comment: use backtick(``) instead of single quotes('')

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). However they are defined by ` instead of ' or ".

Therefore your code should be this

```html
<nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`}>
```